# How to cancel old selection in fullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I use jQuery fullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/unselectAuto/)

I use Selectable version of this calendar (http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar/demos/selectable.html)

It's working fine however I want to cancel/delete my old selections if I continue selecting new dates.

Lets say I chose 1 Jan and gave a title to it.
When I try to select 2 Jan, I want to see only 2 Jan selection.
I thought unselectAuto is for this but I couldnt manage to make it work :(

Any ideas?

I used unselectAuto right under 
selectable: true,
unselectAuto: true,

Comment: By selection do you mean the part where you create a new event via a click on the calendar?

Comment: Yes, new event creation on the calendar. 
But it becomes very crowded if I allow the user to create a new event on each click, I want to avoid that by removing the previous selection

Comment: Each selection on the calendar is rendered, I want to remove the previous render if the user selects another date(renders new event)

Comment: @wallace740 was there ever a solution found for this problem. I have tried calendar.fullCalendar('unselect'); and unselectAuto: true, but it does not unselect the event.

Comment: @JuanGonzales I haven't visited fullCalendar website for the last 8-9 months, maybe there is a new function available, I'm not sure. The last time I tried, once the Event is rendered, it can not be removed until the page is called for another time

Answer (score 6):

First it's still necessary to use the `$('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar('unselect');` function.

The second thing that I needed to do, was to specify how the unselect callback was going to behave (when setting up the fullcalendar options). For me I had to unbind the submit button from my form

```
unselect: function(){
    $('#submitButton').unbind();
},
```

It worked great!

I was able to reach this conclusion after reading this post ["multiple events created"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652789/fullcalendar-1-5-3-multiple-events-created-unable-to-remove-unselected-events)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

u can try this way, this works for me :)

```
 var liveDate = new Date(); // current Date
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         select: function (startDate, endDate) {
                    if (liveDate > startDate) {
                      alert('Selected date has been passed');
                      return false;
                  } else {
                           //do your wish
                  }
         calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem but my user was interfacing directly with the calendar and multiple events were being generated. ie. not through a form with a button and therefore nothing to "unbind" as many of the previous solutions.

To only allow one selection and to clear previous submissions I changed the select function as follows:

```
select: function(start, end) {
   var title = "Desired Booking";
   var eventData;
   eventData = {
       title: title,
       start: start,
       end: end
   };
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);                                                },
```

---

```
select: function(start, end) {
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents')
   var title = "Desired Booking";
   var eventData;
   eventData = {
       title: title,
       start: start,
       end: end
   };
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);                                                },
```

---

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks Paul! That did the trick for me. Spent hours trying to do this

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with unselectAuto also.  Sometimes it would unselect when I didn't want it to, and sometimes it would NOT unselect when I DID want it to.  My solution was to manually trigger the unselect method.

Here's how to unselect all currently selected:

```
$('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
```

You can put this line of code inside custom jQuery events that you bind outside of the plugin.  You can also include it in fullCalendar callbacks, etc...

Hope this helps.

Scott

Comment: select: function(start, end, allDay) {
......
calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
}

is there a way to remove rendered Events?
Each time I select an event, it is rendered automatically

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/unselectAuto/
Whether clicking elsewhere on the page will cause the current selection to be cleared.
I could not make this work, instead of clicking elsewhere I'm trying to click another place on the calendar

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an exemple of Version 5 doing the unselect](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytub5g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
You could do it by :

```
const calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

```
 $('#trainings_modal').on('hidden', function () {
        $('#trainings_modal *').unbind(); // Unbind all events
 });
```

Unbind on hide form with any method (i.e esc press, or out key)