# fullCalendar 1.5.3 multiple events created, unable to remove unselected events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Using fullCalendar, I allow a user to select a day in month view in a big calendar (#cal_big) and the corresponding small calendar in day view, with hours shown (#cal_small) will be displayed.

Whenever the user selects an event (an hour or block of hours) in #cal_small, I will display a confirm/cancel modal. The confirm/cancel modal allows the user to either confirm the booking or cancel the booking (which semantically means that the user does not really want to book that slot after all).

[image: The confirm or cancel modal window]

If the user confirms the booking, I make an ajax call to the server and registers the booking. Once the ajax call returns successfully, I simply hide the current modal and display a "Your booking is successful!" message in a new modal. This part works flawlessly.

If the user cancels the booking, the confirm/cancel modal gets hidden and I attempt to programmatically unselect the current selection and this is where the problem begins.  The unselect does not work and it seems that fullCalendar remembers all these selections which are not confirmed and when the user finally confirms his selection, a whole bunch of previously unconfirmed selections are all sent to the server repeatedly in multiple ajax calls.

[image: Multiple Events created even though the previous two events ought to have been unselected]

Why is this so and how do I prevent fullCalendar from remembering unconfirmed selections?

Here's the code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var todayDate = new Date();

    var myDate = todayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 1);

    var csrfmiddlewaretoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';

    var condo_slug = '{{ condo.slug }}';

    var facility = $("#id_facility");

    var cal_small_options = {
        titleFormat: {
            day: 'dddd' 
        },
        header: {
            left: '',
            center:'title',
            right:'',
        },
        height: 520,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        editable: true,
        minTime: '10:00',
        maxTime: '23:00',
        slotMinutes: 60,
        selectable: true,
        select: function(startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log("selection triggered", jsEvent.handleObj.guid)
            checkAvailability(csrfmiddlewaretoken, condo_slug, facility, startDate, endDate);
            $('#confirm').click(function(){
                confirmBooking(csrfmiddlewaretoken, condo_slug, facility.val(), startDate, endDate)
            });
        },
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            // start and end marks the current date range shown on the calendar
            ajaxShowEvents(facility.val(), condo_slug, start, end, callback); 
        },
        eventClick: function(event) {
            console.log(event.title);
        },
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            // Clear the calendar and retrieve event objects when user selects a facility.
            $('#id_facility').change(function(){
                ajaxShowEvents(facility_id = $(this).val(), start = view.start, end = view.end); 
            });
        }
    };

    var cal_big_options = {
        header: {
            left: '',
            center:'title',
            right: ''
        },
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            if (date < myDate) {
                alert('You cannot book on this day!');
            }
            if (allDay) {
                $('#cal_small').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
            } else {
                alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
            }
        },
        selectable: true,
        unselectCancel: '', 
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            // start and end marks the current date range shown on the calendar
            ajaxShowEvents(facility.val(), condo_slug, start, end, callback); 
        },
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            // Clear the calendar and retrieve event objects when user selects a facility.
            $('#id_facility').change(function(){
                ajaxShowEvents(facility_id = $(this).val(), start = view.start, end = view.end); 
            });
        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

            if(event.start < myDate) {
                alert('You cannot book on this day!');
            }  else {
                // check to see if the booking belongs to user
                ajaxCheckBooking(csrfmiddlewaretoken, event);
                $('#confirm').click(function(){ 
                    ajaxDeleteBooking(csrfmiddlewaretoken, event)
                });
            }
        }
    };

    $('#cal_small').fullCalendar(cal_small_options);

    $('#cal_big').fullCalendar(cal_big_options);

    $('.cancel, .btn_close').click(function() {
            $('#cal_big, #cal_small').fullCalendar('unselect')
            $('#modal-window').modal('hide');
        });

}); // END document ready
```

**UPDATE**

The confirmBooking function as requested:-

```
function confirmBooking(csrfmiddlewaretoken, condo_slug, facility_id, startDate, endDate) {
    // Given condo slug, facility id and the user selected startDate and endDate,
    // send an ajax post request to confirm the booking
    post_data = {csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfmiddlewaretoken, 
                 condo_slug: condo_slug, 
                 facility_id: facility_id, 
                 start_date: startDate.toUTCString(), 
                 end_date: endDate.toUTCString()} 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/facility/ajax-confirm-booking/',
        data: post_data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['status']=='success') {
                message = "Your booking is confirmed!"
                event = new Object();
                event.id = data['id'];
                event.title = "Your Booked Event";
                event.start = startDate;
                event.end = endDate;
                event.allDay = false;   
                $("#cal_big").fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
                $("#cal_small").fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
                // TODO: 
                // * disable the submit and reset buttons
                // * email notification to end user and property manager
            } else if (data['status']=='not logged in') {
                message = "You are not yet logged in!"
                // TODO:
                // * Provide fb login button so user can login.
            } else {
                message = "I am sorry. Something went wrong with your booking"
                // TODO: 
                // * Work on an email notification to site admin if a booking has failed for some reason
            }

            displayModal(message, false);
        }
    });
}; // END confirmBooking
```

Appreciate if some one could elaborate why the .fullCalendar('unselect') call does not work to remove unconfirmed events and how I can possible solve this problem.

Comment: Those "selections" don't look like selections to me, they seem to be real events that get added to the calendar somewhere in those functions that get invoked in your code (like confirmBooking or checkAvailability) - is there anywhere a call to `fullCalendar('renderEvent', ...`?

Comment: I am expecting that the 'previous selection/selected event' to be destroyed every time the user clicks elsewhere, including the 'cancel' button on the modal.  I even verify it by trying to include an explicit `unselect` callback that prints out "event unselected in #cal_small", "event unselected in #cal_big" whenever the user clicks somewhere else other than the confirm button in the modal; and indeed, the console.log does print out these logs. If those previous events are indeed unselected, why are they later considered as part of the selection when user finally "confirms"?

Comment: @Niko there is a `fullCalendar('renderEvent', event)` method call when the confirmBooking ajax call to the server returns successfully, with the purpose of rendering the specific event that is confirmed.  What I don't get is why the previously unselected event is also rendered.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code of your `confirmBooking` function as well?

Comment: Hi @Niko code pasted above. Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it.

It is a dead simple bug which I completely missed.

```
   select: function(startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        console.log("selection triggered", jsEvent.handleObj.guid)
        checkAvailability(csrfmiddlewaretoken, condo_slug, facility, startDate, endDate);
        $('#confirm').click(function(){
            confirmBooking(csrfmiddlewaretoken, condo_slug, facility.val(), startDate, endDate)
        });
    },
```

causes a click event to be bound to the `#confirm` button everytime an event is selected on the calendar.  So if the user keeps selecting event without confirming, the `#confirm` button will keep accumulating different click events with different startDate and endDate.  When the user finally hits the `#confirm` button after repeated indecision, all the click events fire off at one go, resulting in the previously unselected events being sent to the server as an ajax post.

To solve this, I must remember to specify `$('#confirm').unbind()` when the user clicks on the `.cancel` or `.close` button.

Argh... a simple solution but it took me so long to see it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it using this:

```
$( "#confirm" ).dialog({...
```

If I had known about `unbind` earlier, all the things that I had to change would not have been necessary :(